# Grouping JSON results into categories

Tags: php, json

I am trying group some similar numbers from a JSON result set.  I need to group all the [1, X] in small/large number groups and the [0, X] in small/medium/large number groups.

I think I need to do some preprocessing of the data and find the average or maybe a bell curve of the data?

```
$results = json_decode({"data": [[0, 2960], [1, 768], [0, 592], [1, 384], [0, 592], [1, 400], [0, 208], [1, 384], [0, 208], [1, 384], [0, 320], [1, 1056], [0, 576], [1, 400], [0, 208], [1, 384], [0, 592], [1, 768], [0, 208], [1, 400], [0, 592], [1, 768], [0, 208], [1, 768], [0, 208], [1, 400], [0, 1360], [1, 384], [0, 208], [1, 400], [0, 192], [1, 784], [0, 208], [1, 384], [0, 592], [1, 768], [0, 224], [1, 768], [0, 208], [1, 768], [0, 592], [1, 384], [0, 208], [1, 768], [0, 224], [1, 368], [0, 1376], [1, 784], [0, 208], [1, 384], [0, 224], [1, 768], [0, 208], [1, 768], [0, 592], [1, 768], [0, 224], [1, 768], [0, 208], [1, 768], [0, 592], [1, 400], [0, 96], [1, 16], [0, 16], [1, 464], [0, 32], [1, 944], [0, 1968], [1, 0]]});

foreach($flashes as $values) {
  $flash_status = $values[0];
  $length = $values[1];

  // flashing
  if($flash_status == 1) {
    if($length is short)
      // do something
    elseif($length is long)
      // do something
  } else {
    // pausing
    if($length is short)
      // do something
    elseif($length is medium)
      // do something
    elseif($length is long)
      // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you define what is short/medium/long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me.  There is still a hard coded check for a 180 jump, but it will work for my needs right now.

```
        array_multisort($ordering, array_column($ordering, 0));
        $flash_categories = array(
            1 => array (
                'short' => array('min'=> 0,'max'=> 0,),
                'long'  => array('min'=> 0,'max'=> 0,),
            ),
            0 => array (
                'short'  => array('min'=> 0,'max'=> 0,),
                'medium' => array('min'=> 0,'max'=> 0,),
                'long'   => array('min'=> 0,'max'=> 0,),
            ),
        );
        $previous_value = 0;
        $previous_flash = 0;
        $flash_heading_index = 0;
        $flash_headings = array(
            1 => array ('short','long'),
            0 => array ('short','medium','long'),
        );
        foreach($ordering as $values) {
            $flash_status = $values[0];
            $length = $values[1];

            // skip errors
            if($length < 100 || $length > 2000)
                continue;

            if($previous_flash != $flash_status) {
                $previous_flash = $flash_status;
                $flash_heading_index = 0;
                $previous_value = 0;
            }

            // check to see how much difference there is in time
            if($length - $previous_value > 180 && $previous_value != 0)
                $flash_heading_index++;

            // cap off the heading index
            if(!isset($flash_headings[$flash_status][$flash_heading_index]))
                $flash_heading_index = sizeof($flash_headings[$flash_status])-1;

            // set min and max threshold to values
            if($flash_categories[$flash_status][$flash_headings[$flash_status][$flash_heading_index]]['min'] == 0) {
                $flash_categories[$flash_status][$flash_headings[$flash_status][$flash_heading_index]]['min'] = $length;
                $flash_categories[$flash_status][$flash_headings[$flash_status][$flash_heading_index]]['max'] = $length;
            } else
                $flash_categories[$flash_status][$flash_headings[$flash_status][$flash_heading_index]]['max'] = $length;

            $previous_value = $length;
        }
```